# query with where clause with two arguments Android

Tags: android

i want to write a query like the following but exception comes up.

```
mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY,KEY_location  , KEY_GOAL_DATE,KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE, KEY_DATE_CURRENT ,KEY_PRIO,KEY_DONE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_TIME_SPEND,KEY_POSOSTO, KEY_FATHER}, KEY_FATHER + " LIKE" + "'"+ "fid"+"'"+ "AND"+ KEY_ROWID + "LIKE" + "'"+ "uid"+"'", null, null, null, null);
```

anybody who knows the correct syntax of a where clause with two arguments connected with And,Or.i havent found yet anything useful.thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your code is literally as written, you need spaces around the sql key words:

```
mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY,KEY_location  , KEY_GOAL_DATE,KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE, KEY_DATE_CURRENT ,KEY_PRIO,KEY_DONE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_TIME_SPEND,KEY_POSOSTO, KEY_FATHER}, KEY_FATHER + " LIKE " + "'"+ "fid"+"'"+ " AND "+ KEY_ROWID + " LIKE " + "'"+ "uid"+"'", null, null, null, null);
```

I don't know if you might be having some other problems since you don't provide the error you're getting, but that should at least clear up a problem if you aren't seeing it yet.

Comment: 07-11 17:00:45.338: E/AndroidRuntime(717): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "'uid'": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, body, location, goaldate, absolutedate, currentdate, prio, done, category, timespent, pososto, father FROM tasks WHERE father LIKE'fid' AND _idLIKE'uid'

Answer (score 0):

check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#query%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), make a little effort searching buddy ..

Answer (score 0):

Gordon has given you the correct answer. Your error code is still missing the spaces. Also, if fid and uid are variables, then you need to remove the quotes around it and use something like:

```
    KEY_FATHER + " LIKE " + fid + " AND "+ KEY_ROWID + " LIKE " + uid
```

Hope this helps.